# Removing PublicKeyProtectionPolicy in pdfbox

Tags: java, security, pdf, pdfbox

I developed a PDF Encoder which normaly removes the password and enable editing and this stuff.
But now there is a file which is protected by a certificate and it's forbidden to change anything but the type is no security.

I tryed this code:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(input);

AccessPermission perms = new AccessPermission();
perms.setCanAssembleDocument(true);
perms.setCanExtractContent(true);
perms.setCanModify(true);
perms.setCanModifyAnnotations(true);
perms.setCanExtractForAccessibility(true);
perms.setCanFillInForm(true);
perms.setCanPrint(true);
perms.setCanPrintDegraded(true);
perms.setCanExtractForAccessibility(true);

StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("secret", "", perms);
doc.protect(policy);

doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

doc.save(output);
```

But it's only working on password protected files.

Anyone knows the mistake / soultion?

Comment: By *protected by a certificate* do you probably mean that if is signed by a certification signature?

Comment: Correct ... My english isn't that good sry

Comment: If the problem is a signature, simply clear or remove the signature field in question. That being said, though... the program you develop (which *removes the password and enables editing and this stuff*) seems to act against the clear wish of the author of the document in question. Or does your use case differ somehow?

Comment: Please give me some code brackets to clear the signature

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the file is encrypted using certificates and not using standard password method. In this situation unless you have the corresponding certificate for decryption there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Exactly .... so i can open it buts its protected with certificates ... how can I remove this?

Comment: @Luca In comments to the question you affirmed that the PDF is signed by a certification signature. Here you affirm that it is encrypted using a certificate. These are fundamentally different options (which can also be both applied at the same time). So, please start by clarifying what the real protection is. If you don't know the differences, please share the PDF in question.

Comment: The odf program say its protected by certificate or signatur so ... no password I don't know which exactly

Comment: "or" ? These are very different things. Please include a screenshot if you can't share the PDF. Can you open the PDF and view its contents with Adobe Reader or not?

Comment: I need a solution to remove both ... I'll look what I can share ... give me a moment

Comment: I Can open the PDF ... when I go to porperties -> security it says no security but disallows changing the document and assembly or creating template pages ... when I try to change the security Acrobat says: "You cannot change security on this document because the document is signed or certified"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vAK1lcc this is a Link of a picture showing the security ... password security is because I tryed to change it ... when i hit okay it switches back to no security

Comment: You simply have to remove the signature field from the PDF file. I'm not familiar with the PDFBox API so I can't tell you exactly how to achieve this.

Comment: well ... there is a little probelm ... the file don't has a signature field

Comment: What do you get when you call `PDDocument.getLastSignatureDictionary()`? And what do you get when you do `PDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.PERMS)`?